# applying security among menus

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

below is my model

```
public class security
{  
    public long id { get; set; }
    public long user_id { get; set; }
    public long submenu_id { get; set; }
    public bool flag { get; set; }

}
```

it the flag is `true` the user has access to submenu.

Currently what i am doing is . When the user logged in the details in this model will be pulled out and store in seperate session variable.

```
eg: - var c = db.security.where(m=> m.user_id == id).Orderby(id);

if(c.submenu_id == 1 && c.flag == true)
   session["mem_add"] = "true";
else
   session["mem_add"] = "false";
```

Then in the layout view will check this session variable and if `true` the menu will display, but problem is there are `16 sub menus` and can increase it later.So I have to create seperate session variables for each submenu. Is there any better way to solve this problem?

**Edited**

```
@if(Session["mem_add"] == "true")
{
          <li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "UpdateDetail")">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Enrollments.png")" alt=""><span class="title"><b>
    @Resources.Resources.UpdateMyDetail</b> </span> </a></li>
}
```

Comment: How are you current generating these in the view? Do you have a view model to represent the collection of menu items?

Comment: @StephenMuecke no viewmodel for menu..its simply hard coded like in edited part

Comment: One option would be to use a view model to represent your menu items - include properties of the controller and action names, the image path etc and a `bool canView` property. Then you can set the `canView` property for each menu item per user and store the collection in session.

Comment: Other might be be a view model with a series of bool properties - `bool canViewMenu1`, `bool CanViewMenu2` etc. and store that in session and use if to determine which menus to display in the view

Comment: @stephenmuecke any simple example?

Comment: @stephenmuecke thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a view model approach to represent your menu items

```
public class MenuItem
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string ControllerName { get; set; }
  public string ActionName { get; set; }
  public string LinkText { get; set; }
  public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
  public bool CanView { get; set; }
}
```

Then when a user logs in, create a collection of menu items, call your method to get the `security` items for the user, and based on the `flag` property, set the `CanView` property for each menu. Finally store the collection in `Session`

Then create a child only method to generate your menu

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Menu
{
  IEnumerable<MenuItem> model = Session["Menu"] as IEnumerable<MenuItem>;
  // check for null and rebuild if necessary
  return PartialView("_Menu", model);
}
```

and create a partial view `_Menu.cshtml`

```
@model IEnumerable<yourAssembly.MenuItem>
<ul>
  @foreach(var menu in Model)
  {
    if (menu.CanView)
    {
      <li>
        <a href=""@Url.Action(menu.ActionName, menu.ControllerName)">
          <img src="@Url.Content(menu.ImagePath)" alt="">
          <span class="title"><b>menu.LinkText</b></span> 
        </a>
      </li>
    }
  }
</ul>
```

and finally in the layout page, use `Html.Action()` to call the method that generates the menu items

```
@Html.Action("Menu", yourControllerName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your other option would be to create an extension to HtmlHleper, then you can use it to pass a model to your menu and let it generate an MvcHtmlString

```
public MvcHtmlString CreateMenu(this HtmlHelper helper, MenuSecurityModel)
{
   //create tags, string, etc
   //create logic add/remove meun items depending on flag property on model
   //this can be accomplished also by using a base class for your Controllers, 
   //set the the onactionexecuting variable to set the menu[ put it in session accodingly, retrieve when appropriate
   //Call using Html.RenderAction , partial, etc
   return yourHtmlString;
}
```