# What's the standard way to sent the data model to partial view?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view named '_MenuPartial' which has dynamic data from the database.Now I render this view in the '_Layout.cshtml' as below

### _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Html.Partial("_MenuPartial");
```

in my controller, I will send the menu data model to the 'index.view' which is based on the '_Layout.cshtml'.

But My question is that when I want to set the Layout for other views, I need send the menu data model in other views' controller which I think is redundant. So What's the standard way to sent the data model to partial view in the Layout page? How to response a view which has the layout but don't give the data model layout page need?

Hope your answer. thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `@Html.Action(...)` to call a `ChildActionOnly` server method that returns the partial view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Could you give much more details about your answer?

Comment: Refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542818/dynamic-menu-from-database/33557835#33557835) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063808/applying-security-among-menus/32065212#32065212) for some examples

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thanks a lot! that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your model like below,

```
@Html.Partial("_MenuPartial", model)
```

Comment: I know I can pass the model like this for partial view, but I don't want to do this every time I call the view rendered the layout because this partial view  is in the Layout.cshtml

Comment: so you can define this model top of your partial view like @model Model and pass your model from controller return view(model) like this